# About P2P platform Twino - Manual or Auto invest portfolio?

Tags: loans

Recently I start invest on twino platform. Gradually I increase the amount invested and I would like to know if it´s wise to invest in short period loans like 1 - 12 months. Also if the manual invest or Auto reinvest is more profitable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "Requests for specific investment information or buy/sell advice" are off-topic.

Comment: Ok, apologies and my bad for not reading all the guidelines and rules. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Part of the problem with such questions is they are too subjective: specific to one person, and factors like their tolerance to risk etc.  And – in the case of "_is more profitable_" – little more than an exercise in crystal-ball gazing. Questions here need to be more objective: one about the risks/rewards of short-term loans vs. long-term loans _may_ be better suited **but** questioners are expected to do "reasonable" research first (and to show that research and explain why it didn't answer their question).

Comment: I agree. Also I was surprised that the tag P2P was not created yet. I was not aware P2P platform was so unpopular at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike stock, so-called investment in [Peer-to-peer lending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_lending) has no collateral guarantee when shit hits the fan.

Since you mentioned Twino, it is a Lativia P2P loan platform.

> Currently, the most active investors in Latvia’s peer-to-peer lending platforms are residents of Germany, Great Britain, and Estonia.

Bear in mind that, collection of P2P loan is never simple tasks. Compare to the credit card issuers that already earn a 1%~1.5% margin from the sales transaction, P2P income solely depends on the debtor willingness to pay back and how the platform controls the operating cost. 
On the other hand, EU low-interest loan rates mean only people with high-risk default probabilities will resort to P2P, thus a downward spiral to P2P business. If these are not enough to put-off you interest on P2P, you can check out [Twino financial audits report](https://explorep2p.com/twino-update/).

Comment: The report does not look good at all. Still, the experience that I have with small amounts It´s quite positive. I´m European resident and I think P2P platforms are interesting for short term investments especially with some investment protection like Twino allow. Thanks for your answer @mootmoot

Comment: @FrozenButcher Perhaps for the same amount of money, IMHO, you may as well put your money on passive index ETF. Otherwise betting on rubles / china Yuen is still safer than P2P.

Comment: Definitely I´ll check them out now @mootmoot